# What happened with Yori?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

In Tron (1982) Yori had a sort of relationship with both Tron and Kevin Flynn, or at least, she kissed them both. But in Tron Legacy, Kevin Flynn mentions he brought Tron to the Tron System, but no mention of Yori is made whatsoever. How's that Tron, or Kevin Flynn himself, didnt care about her anymore? or did something happened to her?

What happened with Yori?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She is, according to the director of Tron Legacy, alive and well in the '*Tron Universe*'. I think we can assume that she's just off doing something else.

> Cindy Morgan? Her character is not in TRON: Legacy, but that doesn't
> mean she's not in the world of TRON.
>
> <sub><sup>[Yori Lives! - Tron Wiki](https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/Yori_Lives)</sup></sub>